# Making a list of related variables in r

Tags: r

I have two columns of related variables. I would like to make them into a combined list. For example, if the data frame looks like this,

```
A    B
B    C
D    E
```

which indicates that A is related to B, B is related to C, etc.

Then I would like new lists with:

```
A, B, C
D, E
```

Any help would be appreciated. Ideally, using R. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you need `igraph`

Comment: Does your data frame have only one row and 6 columns? if yes, then use `unique(df)`. If I do misunderstand your question, then please clarify and/or give more information.

Answer (score 0):

It would perhaps be easier with a package such as `igraph`, but here is a way to do it in base R...

```
df <- data.frame(X = c("A","B","D"), Y = c("B","C","E"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nodes <- data.frame(node = unique(c(df$X, df$Y)), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)          #set of all unique values

nodes$group <- 1:nrow(nodes)                           #start with each in its own group

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){                           #loop through df
  rowvalues <- unlist(df[i, ])                         #linked pair in row i
  nodes$group[nodes$node %in% rowvalues] <- min(nodes$group[nodes$node %in% rowvalues])
                                                       #set to min group for linked pair
}

#end result is nodes$group containing unique values for each linked group

nodes
  node group
1    A     1
2    B     1
3    D     3
4    C     1
5    E     3

#groups can be extracted as a list with...

split(nodes$node, nodes$group)

$`1`
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$`3`
[1] "D" "E"
```